# Encoding Declaration removed on transform - Access

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am so close to finishing a small personal project, just trying to get round to how to use XML and Access..

Basically, i have been able to compile tables into and XML then get it transformed into a format that the unit im using SHOULD be able to read..

BUT

On the transform, the Encoding declaration is REMOVED from the top line of the XML when viewed in text..

E.g

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DatabaseData>
<Customers>
<Idx>1</Idx>
<FirstName>David</FirstName>
<LastName>James</LastName>
<IconIdx>0</IconIdx>
```

But i need it to include the encoding - so look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Here is my XSLT that i have been using to transform the XML that access compiles.
*(This is only part of it)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<DatabaseData>
  <xsl:for-each select="dataroot/Customers">
    <Customers>
      <Idx>
```

Ive searched high and low on how to make it just include that Encoding information in the Processing declaration!!

This is my process i'm using to Compile and Transform within a Button_Click in access:

```
Private Sub Export_Click()
Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData

'Identify the tables or querys to export
objOtherTbls.Add "Customers"

'Here is where the export takes place
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
DataSource:="Customers", _
DataTarget:="C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDStest.xml", _
AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls

TransformXML "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDStest.xml", _
"C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDSTest.xslt", _
"C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\XML\RDStest.xml"


MsgBox "Export operation completed successfully."
```

HELP PLEASE!

:)

Comment: That should work, but note that UTF-8 is the default encoding if a file doesn't start with a byte-order mark, so it may be that the serializer has decided to leave out the redundant `encoding` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your input, so how would i make it so that it doesnt remove it from the final XML?

Its annoying that my unit that reads it need this declaration! haha

Could it be something to do with Access?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  The `encoding` attribute on your `xsl:output` should do this but like I say, the serializer may be choosing to omit the declaration in the output if it knows it is not necessary.  In the absence of an encoding declaration the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding) says that a parser _must_ treat the document as UTF-8 unless there's a BOM that shows it is UTF-16 or out-of-band information like an HTTP `Content-Type` header that specifies otherwise.

Comment: Hi Ian, the Transformation is done through Access VBA, so im not overly sure what you mean.. sorry! new at all this, so big words confuse me! haha

Hopefully i've added the process used in the Button_Click thats in my form that shows how it is transformed using the XSLT?

does this help in anyway?